# Drop shadow just like in Telerik's demo app

Tags: wpf, telerik, shadow

I wonder how can I create a shadow similar to the one found in teleriks wpf demo? See the [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/Capture.JPG). 
I searched but couldn't find source code of WPF demo app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) to see XAML defined in this demo app.

Comment: Thanks, that's an awesome tool. I'll check in a few hours and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DropShadowEffect ?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect />
    </Grid.Effect>
```